# How to set field width fits with its content

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, js

I'm very new to start learing Aura component and LWC
I have to use **lightning:datatable** to create a list view in related section.
JS file's content:

```
    init: function (component, event, helper) {
component.set('v.columns', [
    {label: '年', fieldName: 'Year__c', type: 'text', wrapText: true },
    {label: '学歴', fieldName: 'EducationaBackground__c', type: 'text'},
    {label: '職歴', fieldName: 'WorkExperience__c', type: 'text'},
    {label: '資格', fieldName: 'Qualification__c', type: 'text'},
]);
```

Here are the result

[image]

But i want field width fits with its content like this
[image]

Is there any solution for this? Thank you!

Comment: set column-widths-mode  to auto.  for aura the name of the attribute is: columnWidthsMode

Comment: @tik27 Thank you. It works